# How to remove base url (codeigniter) in anchor link?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code like this (I used codeigniter):

```
<a href="<?php echo $row->link; ?>">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

`$row->link` output is `www.companyname.com` (from database). But when I click it, the address bar output will be:

```
localhost/mydirproject/www.companyname.com
```

and not:

```
www.companyname.com
```

How can I fix it to remove my base URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `http://` in the beginning of the URL.

---

You have two options.

- Option 1:

  `<a href="http://<?php echo $row->link; ?>">Lorem ipsum</a>`
- Option 2:

  `<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$row->link; ?>">Lorem ipsum</a>`

I've read somewhere that when you construct the anchors without the `http://`, it means that target is expected to be on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to use the [prep_url](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#prep_url) - URL Helper.

> This function will add http:// in the event that a protocol prefix is missing from a URL.

Say, you are taking input from the user and you are not sure if they will provide `http`-prefix or not.